# How to push certain metrics from prometheus to another prometheus

Tags: prometheus

from one Prometheus instance, I want to only send certain metrics to another Prometheus instance.

How do I go about doing that?

(I am relatively new to Prometheus)

Answer (score 5):

To do this, you need to use [federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).
Federation allows you to scrape time series from another Prometheus instance.

Then, if you want to filter and keep only some metrics and not all of them, you need to configure prometheus with [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config).

Comment: Thanks for the post, looked promising, but not exactly what I am looking for. I want my prometheus1 instance to push to the prometheus2 instance. Scrapping from 2 to 1, is not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Prometheus is not designed to push metrics. If that is what you want, you need to have a look at the [pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/). But again, you will not push directly from prom 1 to prom 2. You'll be just pushing from prom 1 to the pushgateway which act as an intermediate exporter. Then prom 2 will scrape the pushgateway.

Comment: Just to be clear : Using the pushgateway for this scenario is useless as it will just add complexity for a result that can be achieved way simpler with federation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; the scenario is that prom1 and prom2 are owned be different companies, and prom1 contains metrics regarding apps owned by the owner of prom2. Prom1 has multiple metrics, not just those for the prom2 owner, so I kinda have to use the pushgateway to allow the securely sharing of specific metrics.